# How to properly handle stressed chars in controlled react input?

Tags: reactjs

I have a weird issue when trying to input a word with stressed chars (Greek in my case) in a controlled react input like:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.field} 
// and 
onChange={event => this.setState({ field: event.target.value } />
```

By default when I want to input a stressed char, I need to press the semi-colon key, followed by the letter, so `; + ο = ό`.

onChange() is triggered 3 times:
1. value="΄" (the result of pressing ;)
2. value=""
3. value="ό"

The first is due to the keypress of ; and the other two happen together and are the result of the os/browser deleting the previous on and replacing it with the proper stressed letter.

However, despite the fact setState() is called 3 times, the component calls render only 2 times (once for the 1st and once for the 3rd setState) and the result is "΄ό".

Afaik this only affects macOS/iOS.

Anyone has a workaround for this issue?